# Не подключается SFML на mac os, xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, sfml

По официальной инструкции на сайте скачал все файлы, положил в нужные папки.
Но только создаю приложение и пытаюсь его запустить - xcode пишет: SFML/Audio.hpp not found, SFML/Graphics.hpp not found.
Что делать?

Comment: может и не то, какая версия Xcode?

Comment: @VAndrJ последняя

Comment: Не пробовали на 8.2.1?

Comment: @VAndrJ А как попробовать? Удалять текущую версию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что мой проект собирался с помощью CLion и CMake. В файле cmake надо было прописать include для sfml и все.